# how to get image url from database in php?

Tags: php

I have problem to show image url-link to my showdb.php
My current db record:

|**_id_____|____name_____|_image**|
|____1_____|__banana____|banana.jpg|
|____2_____|__aple______|apple.jpg |

What I want to do is how banana.jpg or under image column to be www.myhost.com/image/banana.jpg when it showed in record.php?

What I get right now :

```
{"posts":[
{
    "name":"banana",
    "image":banana.jpg}, // FROM THIS
{
    "name":"apple",
    "image":apple.jpg} // FROM THIS
]}
```

What I want :

```
{"posts":[
{
    "name":"banana",<br>
    "image":www.myhost.com/image/banana.jpg}, // BECOME THIS
{
    "name":"apple",<br>
    "image":www.myhost.com/image/apple.jpg} // BECOME THIS
]}
```

And this is my current code to show my db record:

```
if ($rows) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Available!";
$response["posts"]   = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {

$post             = array();
$post["name"]  = $row["name"];
$post["image"]    = $row["image"];


//update our repsonse JSON data
array_push($response["posts"], $post);

}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);


} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
```

is posible to change those code?
or if any link to do that, I'm so pleased :))

Thank You, for your answer :))) *and sorry if my english is bad :)

============================================================
Solved by: @KhaledBentoumi

Just add

```
'www.yourhost.com/folder/'(dot)$row["image"]; => 'www.yourhost.com'.$row["image"];
```

but, it will change `/` to `\/` : `'www.yourhost.com\/folder\/file.jpg`

add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`, for example:

```
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';

echo json_encode($url), "\n";

echo json_encode($url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "\n";
```

happy coding guys! :))

Comment: Change `$post['image']` to `'http:\\...\'.$row['image']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply append `www.myhost.com/image/` to your image entrie in the post array

```
if ($rows) {
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Post Available!";
$response["posts"]   = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {

$post             = array();
$post["name"]  = $row["name"];
$post["image"]    = 'www.myhost.com/image/'.$row["image"]; // Append here


//update our repsonse JSON data
array_push($response["posts"], $post);

}

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);


} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
die(json_encode($response));
}
```

Comment: @ObySaputra your welcome im happy to help, could you mark the answer as accepted so that it may help someone  in the future ?

Comment: ihave checked and the result is "www.myhost.com\/image\/apple.jpg" anyway to get " / " not " \/ " ??

Comment: @KhaledBentoumi and I'm waiting :))

Comment: @ObySaputra add `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` to json_encode function  `json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` Keep in mind that when you read it in javascript the slashes will be unescaped automaticly, and that json_encode  only escapes things that need to be escaped for the string to work when you read it in your Javascript

Comment: @KhaledBentoumi okay, its work fine for image. Loading smoothly. May have effect for date/time or somethings. I'll edit my post now :)

Answer (score 0):

Use simple concatenation:

```
$post["image"]    = "www.myhost.com/image/".$row["image"];
```